# Display specific rows in crystal report vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I'm having a problem on my crystal report. Is there any way on how can I display specific rows in a crystal report? For example all records with an ID of 00234 will be displayed in a full crystal report. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Use Section Expert.

Go to `Report -> Section Expert`. Select the `Details` section on the left side. Click the Formula icon beside the `Suppress` option on the right, and enter a formula in the editor.  Rows that evaluate to True will not appear on the report.  If you enter `[ID] <> 00234`, then only rows with ID = 00234 will appear on the report.